# Postgresql How to Group By and keep all columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know there are similiar questions but i think i have an unique situation.

I'm trying to develop a plugin for Redmine 3. Using Postgresql.

There is a table named TimeEntry and contains a log file for which user works at which issue.

I have a table named TimeEntry like this;

```
ID      user_id   project_id    issue_id    hours
```

```
1       1         1             1           6
2       1         2             1           5
3       1         1             1           3
4       2         2             1           2
5       1         1             2           7
6       3         1             2           8
7       2         2             1           4
```

And i'm fetching this table for its project id's. But as you can see there is some kinda duplicate rows there. I want to make them one and sum their hours into one.

For example ids with 1 and 3. Same user works in same project in same issue. I'm trying to make it look like one row but their hours summed, like 9.

I can accomplish this by grouping in ActiveRecord, but there is one more problem. Since i'm using Rails 4, i need to access Issue subject. For this i was doing for example, TimeEntry.first.issue.subject gives me Subject of  that Issue.

If i do this in Rails Console i just get some array like this;

```
TimeEntry.group(:issue_id).sum(:hours)
=> {1=>9.0, 2=>5.0}
```

But by this way i can not acces this item's issue since there is not an issue_id anymore.

How can i get around of this?

Thanks.
PS: I'm not experienced about asking questions on stackoverflow so if i did something wrong or something else, please be kind. Also there may be some grammar issues because English is not my native language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TimeEntry
  .group(:user_id, :issue_id)
  .select('user_id, issue_id, sum(hours) as hours')
```

This should returns a list of `TimeEntry` for each User/Issue pair. For each `TimeEntry`, only 3 fields will be set :

- the `user_id`
- the `issue_id`
- the `hours` attribute which will be the sum of all hours of the pair

Comment: Thank you its worked! And i see now why i'm failing with my grouping. But there is a simple typo error in your solution i think. I just correct :user to :user_id and :issue to :issue_id and it works.